# python JSON to dict check if single or multiple children

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I am using python2.7 and receive dynamically a JSON string that I need to parse.

The resulting dict looks as follows"

`{
        u'queueId': u'channel.presence'
        u'name': u'presence.message'
        u'timestamp': 1467756404358
        u'webhookId': u'U3P3Xw'
        u'serial': u'e7da73f968767379:37'
        u'data': {

            u'channelId': u'private-cc-259970d91ab44af38393130e95de7057'
            u'site': u'eu-central-1-A'
            u'presence': {

                u'action': u'enter'
                u'connectionId': u'LA84hfOd_w'
                u'data': u'a012a914cce6096c4a02a29da51dbc58'
                u'clientId': u'a012a914cce6096c4a02a29da51dbc58'
            }
        }
    },
    {
        u'queueId': u'channel.presence'
        u'name': u'presence.message'
        u'timestamp': 1467756452665
        u'webhookId': u'U3P3Xw'
        u'serial': u'e7da73f968767379:40'
        u'data': {

            u'channelId': u'private-a012a914cce6096c4a02a29da51dbc58'
            u'site': u'eu-central-1-A'
            u'presence': [
                {
                    u'timestamp': 1467756404550
                    u'connectionId': u'LA84hfOd_w'
                    u'clientId': u'a012a914cce6096c4a02a29da51dbc58'
                    u'action': 3
                    u'data': u'a012a914cce6096c4a02a29da51dbc58'
                    u'id': u'LA84hfOd_w-2:0'
                }
            ]
        }
    },`

As you can see from the example data the [data][presence] can have either just a single object or multiple objects.

My testing for that fails utterly with the exception:

`Error: list indices must be integers, not str`

My code:

`for ji in json_data['items']:
    channel_id = ji['data']['channelId']
    logger.debug("ChannelID: %s" % channel_id)
    found_special_case = False
    if len(ji['data']['presence']) > 1 :
        for ch in ji['data']['presence']:
            ...`

Unfortunatly the check `len(ji['data']['presence']) > 1` is also true when there is only one item. In that case `ch` becomes 'action' instead of the child item.

How can I check whether there is a single or several items in a dictionary?

Comment: what you posted is not valid, can you post a usable sample?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`isinstance()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance) to determine if the item is a list or not:

```
presence = ji['data']['presence']
if isinstance(presence, list):
    # ...
```

Though, if I understand you correctly, this is the logic you are looking for:

```
presence = ji['data']['presence']
if isinstance(presence, dict):  # or: if not isinstance(presence, list):
    presence = [presence]

for ch in presence:
    # ...
```

Comment: Well, that makes sense. Thank you !

Comment: @PadraicCunningham thanks, it still feels so far away :) And you are so close to all the swags from SO :)

Comment: I never imagined I would get anywhere near 100k, seems a very long way when you start with 1 but the addiction helps.  I swear after 100k i will cut back though :D

Comment: @PadraicCunningham addiction definitely helps. I think we need professional help - is there a stackexchange site about helping others with stackexchange addiction?

Comment: @alecxe, hopefully not, that would probably end up as just replacing one addiction with another  :)